# Digital Zoom practical use?

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, signal-processing, photoshop

I would like to hear any practical uses of Digital Zoom.
I only see disadvantages of it like:
 When enabled the quality drops
 When enabled camera gets very sensitive so blurs
 When enabled it's useless

I see it only as a way to crop the image but that can be done in software later and with better view of an image as well as you can select the part which you would like to crop.

So anyone, please state any useful example of digital zoom :)
I am curious to know.

Comment: Try http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **Yes, the digital zoom is very useful!** See [my answer here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/is-digital-zoom-really-useful/15504#15504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convenience feature for people who are not very intimate with digital image processing. And, in addition, the "zoomed" (cropped) image does not require as much disk space.